How can I measure paid search/SEM effects on sales with MMM while accounting for funnel effects?
I am reading hello fresh approach on building a Direct and Indirect marketing mix model to avoid funnel effects (details in this link : https://engineering.hellofresh.com/bayesian-media-mix-modeling-using-pymc3-for-fun-and-profit-2bd4667504e6 )
Direct model is using top funnel spend to predict on sales. While Indirect model is using top funnel spend to predict low funnel spend. Basically the CAC for Upper funnel is adjusted based on the indirect model result.
Now my question is, how can i adjust the CAC for the low funnels?
Should I make an all inclusive model that includes all top funnel spend and predicted low funnel spend to predict sales?
